# Responsive Menu on Background Image

Tags: css, responsive-design, responsive

I have a responsive menu on top of the background image.

```
<div
    class="header-slides"
    data-slides='["https://picjumbo.imgix.net/HNCK1654.jpg?q=40&w=1650&sharp=30",
                  "https://picjumbo.imgix.net/HNCK2106.jpg?q=40&w=1650&sharp=30"]'
>
<ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
  <h2>Header Message</h2>
</div>
```

The menu works fine except when I toggle it, the menu stays on top of the background image. What I want to achieve is when I toggle, I want to have the menu push down the background image and be positioned at the top of the page.

Is this doable?

[You can find the code sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/hoL986dp/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put the `<ul class="topnav"></ul>` before `<div class"header-slides">` for it to be possible.

[Here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoL986dp/23/)

Here is som HTML:

```
 <ul class="topnav">
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">

  </li>
</ul> 
<div
    class="header-slides"
    data-slides='["https://picjumbo.imgix.net/HNCK1654.jpg?q=40&w=1650&sharp=30",
                  "https://picjumbo.imgix.net/HNCK2106.jpg?q=40&w=1650&sharp=30"]'
>
  <a id="menuIcon" href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  <h2>Header Message</h2>
</div>
```

And css:

```
[data-slides] {
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/300/); /* Default image. */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: background 1s linear;
}

/* Use additional CSS to control the `height` of `[data-slides]`, like so: */

.header-slides {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

@media all and (min-width: 48em) {
    .header-slides { height: 500px; }
}

h2  { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 100px; 
   color: white;
   font-size: 4em;
   line-height: 1em;
   text-align: center;
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}

ul.topnav {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 97%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#menuIcon{
  display:none;
}

ul.topnav li {float: right; padding-right}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #333;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:last-child) {display: none;}
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #000;
    width:100%;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  #menuIcon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 14px 17px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
  #menuIcon:hover{
    background-color: #000;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @stannersuperior wrote, first move your nav-list above the "header-slides"-DIV. Then you won't see the icon (white in white), so you have to add some background to it, like `ul.topnav { background: #444; }` Then it will work, however, with a kind of menu bar on top (that only contains the icon).

You can also leave out that background-color and instead add a negative margin-top to `.header-slides` (around -50px), which looks nice at first (image behind menu icon, no dark top bar), but inconsistent when the menu is open, since the last menu entry will have the image backgound, the others not.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebn7syun/